# What is the purpose of cv::MatExpr?

Tags: opencv

OpenCV arithmetic operations produce a [`cv::MatExpr`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html), for example:

`MatExpr`[`operator+`](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html#a366cabf9cd5b9a9fb0e313570c5b3cac)`(const Mat & a, const Mat &b);`

I see that this is used to represent an expression before it is evaluated. What is the purpose of doing this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates

Comment: @Miki This seems to be different because `cv::MatExpr` is not templated.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's say you have this expression: 
`Mat A = 3 + B * 5;`
where `B` is also a `Mat`. If the operators `+` and `*` where to return a `Mat`, `B * 5` would have create a temporary `Mat` and then the `+` operator would have create another `Mat`. Instead, `B * 5` returns a `MatExpr` that doesn't actually creates a `Mat`, it just "remembers" the operation it needs to peform. Then, the `+` operator creates another `MatExpr` and only the `=` operator creates a `Mat`, thus avoiding the temporary `Mat`. 
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation