# Strange uint8_t conversion with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, floating-point, integer

I have encountered a strange behavior from the Matrix class in OpenCV regarding the conversion float to uint8_t.
It seems that OpenCV with the Matrix class converts float to uint8_t by doing a ceil instead of just truncating the decimal.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

int main() {

  cv::Mat m1(1, 1, CV_8UC1);
  cv::Mat m2(1, 1, CV_8UC1);
  cv::Mat m3(1, 1, CV_8UC1);
  m1.at<uint8_t>(0, 0) = 121;
  m2.at<uint8_t>(0, 0) = 105;
  m3.at<uint8_t>(0, 0) =  82;
  
  cv::Mat x = m1 * 0.5 + m2 * 0.25 + m3 * 0.25;
  printf("%d \n", x.at<uint8_t>(0, 0));
  
  uint8_t r = 121 * 0.5 + 105 * 0.25 + 82 * 0.25;
  printf("%d \n\n", r);

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
108
107
```

Do you know why this append and how to correct this behavior ?

Thank you,

Comment: "matrix expressions" evaluate according to OpenCV semantics, which apparently means that an integer matrix, times a float scalar, results in an int matrix again, not a float matrix. -- the products would be (60.5, 26.25, 20.5) as floats, but they're probably rounded to integers individually, which is (61, 26, 21) and that is 108. -- the fact that you can `at<uint8_t>` that matrix and *not* get garbage means the intermediate results and the final result are uint8, not float

Comment: Thank you Christoph for your answer. Yes, the matrix stays as int, expect that the int conversion truncate the decimal, therefore the 60.5, 26.25, 20.5 float values should be (60, 26, 20) which gives 106. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The strange behavior is a result of [cv::MatExpr](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.4/d1/d10/classcv_1_1MatExpr.html) and [Lasy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) usage as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964583/what-is-the-purpose-of-cvmatexpr/45898514).

The actual result equals:

```
round(round(121*0.5 + 105*0.25) + 82*0.25) = 108
```

- The rounding is used because the element type is UINT8 (integer type).
- The computation order is a result of the "Lasy evaluation" strategy.

---

Following the computation process using the debugger is challenging, because OpenCV implementation includes operator overloading, templates, macros and pointer to functions...

The actual computation is performed in `static void scalar_loop` function in

```
dst[x] = op::r(src1[x], src2[x], scalar);
```

When for example: `src1[x] = 121`, `src2[x] = 105` and `scalar = 0.5`.

It executes an inline function:

```
inline uchar c_add<uchar, float>(uchar a, uchar b, float alpha, float beta, float gamma)
{ return saturate_cast<uchar>(CV_8TO32F(a) * alpha + CV_8TO32F(b) * beta + gamma); }
```

The actual rounding is in `saturate_cast`:

```
template<> inline uchar saturate_cast<uchar>(float v)        { int iv = cvRound(v); return saturate_cast<uchar>(iv); }
```

`cvRound` uses an SIMD intrinsic `return _mm_cvtss_si32(t)`
It's equivalent to: `return (int)(value + (value >= 0 ? 0.5f : -0.5f));`

---

The Lasy evaluation stages builds `MatExpr` with `alpha` and `beta` scalars.

```
cv::Mat x = m1 * 0.5 + m2 * 0.25 + m3 * 0.25;  //m1 = 121, m2 = 105, m3 = 82
```

The expression is built recursively (hard to follow).

Following the "operator +" function (using the debugger):

```
MatExpr operator + (const MatExpr& e1, const MatExpr& e2)
{
    MatExpr en;
    e1.op->add(e1, e2, en);
    return en;
}
```

---

```
State 1:
e1.a data = 121 (UINT8)
e1.b (NULL)
e1.alpha = 0.5
e1.beta  = 0

e2.a data = 105 (UINT8)
e1.b (NULL)
e1.alpha = 0.25
e1.beta  = 0

Result:
en.a data = 121 (UINT8)
en.b data = 105 (UINT8)
en.alpha = 0.5
en.beta = 0.25



State 2:
e1.a data = 121 (UINT8)
e1.b data = 105 (UINT8)
e1.alpha = 0.5
e1.beta = 0.25


e2.a data = 82 (UINT8)
e1.b (NULL)
e1.alpha = 0.25
e1.beta  = 0

en.a data = 87 (UINT8)   <--- 121*0.5 + 105*0.25 = 86.7500 rounded to 87
en.b data = 82 (UINT8)
en.alpha = 1
en.beta = 0.25



Stage 3: (in MatExpr::operator Mat() const):
m data = 108 (UINT8)   <--- 87*1 + 82*0.25 = 87 + 20.5 = 107.5 rounded to 108
```

---

You may try to follow the computation process using the debugger.
It requires building OpenCV from sources, in Debug configuration, and a lot of patient...

Comment: Thank you very much for you in depth answer !

Comment: Your welcome. I think you should try debugging OpenCV code, instead of just believing my answer is correct.

Comment: When using `cv::Mat x = (cv::Mat)(m1 * 0.5) + (cv::Mat)(m2 * 0.25) + (cv::Mat)(m3 * 0.25);` the result is `106`.