# OpenCV Mat cpp operation only on condition

Tags: python, c++, opencv, matrix, indexing

Having a hard time figuring out how to do this python operation in c++ without looping.

The goal is to perform an operation only on a part of the cv::Mat that meets a condition.

In this case, scaling values of the image that were originally between -5 and 5..

```
image[-5<image<5] = image[-5<image<5]*2+1
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting and not pointing to another exact question on the site?

Comment: A downvote typically signifies that a question is unclear or doesn't show signs of research or sometimes the poster entirely forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I don't see what's unclear about the question, and I have tried to search for something similar without finding an easily accessible answer.

Comment: The question is how to do a conditional operation in opencv like the python example posted..\

Comment: Use loops. There's no single function that can do this, and repeated passes/allocation of multiple intermediate arrays will hurt a lot. If you need it faster, then a [`parallel_for_`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d3/d89/group__core__parallel.html#ga3384df8fae1eceb35e9ae12a7a06aa43) with a simple lambda can likely do a good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct conversion between NumPy and OpenCV (C++).
We may use a mask, and get a syntax that looks "vectorized":

```c++
cv::Mat mask = (image > (-5)) & (image < 5);
cv::copyTo(image*2+1, image, mask);
```

---

- `cv::Mat mask = (image > (-5)) & (image < 5);`
  Creates a mask with `255` where conditions are true, and 0 where false.
- `cv::copyTo(image*2+1, image, mask);`
  Copy the values `image*2+1` to `image`, only in pixels where `mask` != `0`.

---

More compact implementation:

```c++
cv::copyTo(image*2+1, image, (image > (-5)) & (image < 5));
```

---

**Note about efficiency:**
The above example is probably less efficient then using for loops.
The purpose is to solve it in a syntax that is closer to NumPy (assuming you prefer code that resembles NumPy [or more compact] over efficiency).
In case you care about efficiency, using for loops, is probably better solution.

Comment: How does this perform compared to a pair of loops? I have a feeling that all those extra allocations (and the fact you have to iterate over the same sized array multiple times) will make those OpenCV versions slower.

Comment: Also the increment by one should use a mask as well to match what OP has.

Comment: @DanMašek, both of your comments are correct. I had to assume that the OP doesn't care about efficiency so much.

Comment: Thank you, I had tried this but incorrectly made a mask using mask= -5 < image < 5. Part of the reason for the question was thinking that maybe the built-in opencv operations would make use of optimizations,

Comment: OpenCV has the [cv::MatExpr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39964583/what-is-the-purpose-of-cvmatexpr) feature, that is highly optimized, but it is limited to relatively simple cases. It is not trivial to implement the code above correctly in a way that is faster. We also have to consider the fact that OpenCV clips the result to the valid range of the data type (unlike NumPy). Naive code that uses `if` statements may be slower (hard to tell)...